# Inserting Strings at specific locations within text

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to convert some text into Latex format.

```
123 {\i1}e11 e22{\i0} asa ds dawdas a as<asd a<asd <ads sasdasdasd
```

My goal is to place everything which is between {\i1} and {\i0} within $  and $ instead and to add a " \ " between every word.

Expected result:

```
123 $e11 \ e22 $ asa ds dawdas a as<asd a<asd <ads sasdasdasd
```

or (this is also okay)

```
123 $e11 \ e22 \ $ asa ds dawdas a as<asd a<asd <ads sasdasdasd
```

What I have tried:

```
text = '123 {\i1}e11 e22{\i0} asa ds dawdas a as<asd a<asd <ads sasdasdasd'
a = re.sub(r'{\\i1}(.*?){\\i0}', r' $\1$', text)
```

> 123 $e11 e22$ asa ds dawdas a as

**...but how do I get those " \ " in-between ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
text = '123 {\i1}e11 e22{\i0} asa ds dawdas a as<asd a<asd <ads sasdasdasd'
rx = r'{\\i1}(.*?){\\i0}'
a = re.sub(rx, lambda x: r' ${} $'.format(r" \ ".join(x.group(1).split())), text)
print(a) # => 123  $e11 \ e22 $ asa ds dawdas a as<asd a<asd <ads sasdasdasd
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/1NOc7n).

Here, `re.sub(rx, lambda x: r' ${} $'.format(r" \ ".join(x.group(1).split())), text)` is a call to `re.sub` where the second argument is a lambda expression. The match is passed there as `x`, `x.group(1)` is the "equivalent" of the `\1` backreference in the string replacement pattern. It is split with whitespaces and joined back with space+backslash+space and together with space+dollar sequences on both ends is inserted into the resulting string instead of the match value.